# CSS stylesheet mobile layout, massive white gap to the right of page

Tags: html, css, layout, mobile

I am adding mobile layout and everything is set however there is a massive white gap of around 200-300px on a page, I have used overflow-x: hidden however on the iphone it still allows the scroll.

Screenshot : https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tsXg.jpg

I dont know whats causing the gap im boggled! Spent a good 3 hours looking for it.

Thanks!

Comment: Please include your HTML in the jsFiddle.  Also please include your problem code in this post as per stackoverflow regs: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84342/answer-that-only-contains-a-link-to-jsfiddle

Comment: I will add the html now, and I dont know where the problem is, hence the full CSS

Comment: Without the css hard to say. I have seen effects like this caused  by using padding on div element that push the object beyond the viewport or fixed pixel widths. Are you using any sort of responsive framework for the mobile ui? Also are you using fixed dimensions for elements or using percentages or em for sizing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you used the viewport meta tag?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```